# flutter evaluate if var is integer or string

Tags: flutter

i need to evaluate what type is a variable to make some switch,there are any way to evaluate a varible to get his type, like val() or something similar. i need to do something for integers and other for string.

i alreaedy try to using a switch, like this,

```
 switch (selector) {
case  int :
  print('value is a integer');
    break;
case  String:
    print('value is a String');
   break;
```

}

but how i do this, if switch can allow compare mixed type of vars?

thank you

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can use the keyword `is` or switch over `runtimeType` :

```
dynamic foo = 42;
if (foo is int) {
  print("Hello");
}
switch (foo.runtimeType) {
  case int: {
    print("World");
  }
}
```

Consider using `is` instead of directly using `runtimeType`. As `is` works with subclasses. While using `runtimeType` is a strict comparison.

Answer (score 10):

You can use something like :

```
if(selector.runtimeType == int) print("Hello")
```

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple:

```
dynamic a = "hello";
if (a.runtimeType == int)
  print("a is int");
else if (a.runtimeType == String) 
  print("a is String");
```

Answer (score 1):

Create this extension:

```dart
extension EvaluateType on Object? {
  bool get isInt => this is int;
  bool get isString => this is String;
}
```

**Usage:**

```dart
void main() {
  Object? foo;
  
  foo = 0;
  print(foo.isInt); // true
  print(foo.isString); // false
}
```